# how to extract varible from scope and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this json data

```
$scope.ths=function () {
    $http.get('userData.php').success(function (user){
       $scope.user = user;
    });
```

this the result `[{"id":1,"name":"Azam ,age":1,date":"2018-04-17 00:00:00"}]`;

what i'm looking for is how to extract id, name and use them as JavaScript variables  just like this

```
var numb=id; var user=name;
```

Comment: `user` is an array. You can get values like `user[0].id,` `user[0].name`

Comment: thanks for your help @Nikhil Aggarwal

Answer (score -1):

Convert the angular array to object like below
var obj= {};
angular.extend(obj,$scope.user);
Now you can fetch id and name like
var id = obj.id;
and var name = obj.name;